# conversion of corrupted pdf to structural pdf in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am developing pdf from wickedpdf and it not structured and i cant perform any processing on it like i cant do watermarking on it as it gives me wiered dimensions. Is there any way to structure that pdf using ruby code?

Comment: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf have you gone through this?

Comment: obviuosly..:( but i didnt find any way to produce proper formatted pdf.

Comment: yes watermarking the generated pdf.. and text is variable so need to find dimensions of pdf.